# Alterar a fonte através do xml

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho as fontes do meu aplicativo em :

> main > assets >fonts

Existe alguma forma de passar diretamente no xml? (`android:typeface=""`)

Ou apenas via Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago,

Sua pergunta é bastante interessante. A solução que sempre usei foi essa que segue na minha resposta. Inclusive até hoje não achei outra e gostaria de simplesmente fazer também por XML, seria tão mais fácil!!! Se descobrir algum jeito melhor, nos conte! :-)

Você pode definir uma especialização de TextView e aplicar a fonte que precisar. A classe abaixo pode fazer isso por você, porém é importante dizer que deixe essa classe um pouco mais flexível, para reutilizá-la em outros projetos, trabalhando melhor o método setFont.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThiagoLuizTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }
    public ThiagoLuizTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }
    public ThiagoLuizTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/RobotNew.ttf");
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Para usar no XML, segue um exemplo: (Claro vai depender de onde sua classe está localizada na estrutura de seu projeto, portanto com.projeto.ui deve ser substituído para sua estrutura de pacotes)

- Tentei usar uma biblioteca chamada [Caligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) porém o desempenho ficou péssimo no profiling de código. Utiliza reflexão para algumas coisas e não gostei. Voltei a fazer do meu jeito mesmo. Em casos de usar sua textview customizada, lembre-se de adotar o padrão viewholder corretamente em listas para não ter problemas.

Espero ter ajudado e um abraço,

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta! É uma ótima alternativa! Bem menos trabalhosa!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski legal! Que bom que ajudou! Um abraço!

Comment: Cara, não vou marcar como certa por enquanto  (esperamos q alguém saiba como) por se tratar como carregar com o XML!  Mas ajudou bastante!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski com toda razão amigo, como eu mesmo respondi, também não sei se existe uma solução que seria melhor mesmo! Aliás, se existir, será muito bem vinda e muito melhor do que sempre implementei e conforme te instruí! Fique tranquilo :-)